# Get uninstall application path by name issue

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I want to get application uninstall path by app's name from registry.

**Code:**

```
QString Test::getAppUninstallPath(QString name)
{
    QString uninstallLocation;
    QStringList allCurrentUserKeys;
    QSettings registryKeyCurrentUser("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall", QSettings::NativeFormat);
    allCurrentUserKeys = registryKeyCurrentUser.allKeys();

    for (QString key : allCurrentUserKeys) {
        if (key.contains("DisplayName")) {
            if (registryKeyCurrentUser.value(key).toString() == name) {
                uninstallLocation = registryKeyCurrentUser.value("UninstallString").toString();
            }
        }
    }

    return uninstallLocation;
}
```

It returns nothing. How to get the app's uninstall path? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **hskoglund**. Because I'm dealing with hierarchies/nested keys, so I should use the `beginGroup()`/`endGroup()`.

**Code:**

```
    QString uninstallLocation;
    QSettings registryKeyLM("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall", QSettings::NativeFormat);

    auto allGroups = registryKeyLM.childGroups();
    for (auto group : allGroups)
    {
        registryKeyLM.beginGroup(group);

        for (auto key : registryKeyLM.childKeys())
            if ("DisplayName" == key)
                if (registryKeyLM.value(key) == name)
                    uninstallLocation = registryKeyLM.value("UninstallString").toString();

        registryKeyLM.endGroup();
    }

    return uninstallLocation;
```